# Google reCaptcha does not displayed when google is restricted

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using google reCaptch in one intranet portal. One user has reported issue issue that captcha is not getting displayed as google is blocked. 
I want to display error message to user for the same on client side.
Please help me with this!

Comment: You could try to reach google via XMLHTTP request and display the error message on failure or add the code for the recaptcha on success.
Consider an alternative to recaptcha as this renders your form useless (obviously)

Comment: Yes...I think this will be a good idea.